# How does the styling of the root <html> (HTMLHtmlElement) tag work?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand why the following CSS styling of the root `<HTML>` element works that way.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var counterByElementName = { html: 0, body: 0 };
    function display()
    {
        document.getElementById( "result" ).innerHTML = JSON.stringify( counterByElementName, null, "\t" );
    }
    function moveListener( event )
    {
        counterByElementName[ this.nodeName.toLowerCase() ] ++;
        display();
    }
    document.body.addEventListener( "mousemove", moveListener );
    document.body.parentNode.addEventListener( "mousemove", moveListener );
    display();
};
```

```css
html, body
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 2em;
    top: 2em;
    right: 2em;
    bottom: 2em;
}

html
{
    border: 2px dashed gray;
    background: yellow;
}

body
{
    border: 2px solid red;
    background: orange;
}

#result
{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Specifically, the `<HTML>` element has a `position: absolute`, and its (dashed) border is correctly displayed at a `2em` distance from the "container" element (either iframe or browser window), **however** its yellow background color is extended **past** its border, to fill the entire area of the container.
By comparison, the orange background of the `<BODY>` element does **not** spread past its red border.
Also, as you can see, mouse events even outside the border of the `<HTML>` element are still sent to this element, which is not the case for the body.

While I think I understand the rationale behind this (we don't want to have some space that belongs to no element outside of the root element), I would like to have at least some (basic) explanation of the exact rules that apply here, and how much this behavior can be relied upon between different browsers and platforms.

I have put the snippet on Codepen as well [here](https://codepen.io/njor/pen/dqxELm).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The JS you have provided doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question. Could you please remove it and the js tag as it's extraneous?

Comment: @scrappedcola I agree that the tag is irrelevant, however the provided code seems relevant to me. He's questioning the true bounds of the `<html>` element, making specific mention that the element still handles the mouse events outside of it's `border`. The question doesn't *rely* on these mouse events, but it provides some additional information, and more importantly, shows that OP has investigated/researched the issue before asking.

Comment: The yellow is reasonably well understood. [CSS 2.2 Section 14.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/colors.html#background) (para 3) says that "the background of the root element becomes the background of the canvas". The event hit area that determines which event listeners are fired for which mouse locations is more interesting. The browsers seem consistent on how it works, but I can't find where it is specified.